# How to GET variables from URL and insert it within POST in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I am new in PHP and javascript and need help with the following code
I want to get the value from browser URL that tag with "org" and use it in javascript; as example "http://localhost/nmt/index.php?org=table1" I want to put the "org" value inside the URL/ inside the POST $.post("ch1.php?org=table1", instead of table1 put the GET value
This is the part from code

$(document).ready(function () {    showGraph1();    });       function showGraph1()  {  {  $.post("ch1.php?org=**table1**",   function (data) {   console.log(data);
That If possible replace table1 with the value from URL

Comment: Simplest answer is

<script>
var org = "<?=$_GET["ORG"]?>"
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your variable into the javascript.

```
<script>
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($_GET["org"]); ?>; 
</script>
```

You also can [get the url parameter directly from js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters).

Comment: Thanks for your response but I want put the value inside the URL/ inside the POST  $.post("ch1.php?org=table1",   instead of table1 put the GET value